# Detect system wide key-press? (node.js?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

Is it possible to detect a key-press even if my node application is not in focus?

Back in the days there was this tool for [warcraft](http://www.dota-utilities.com/2009/10/warkey-warcraft-inventory-hotkeys.html) which would quickly move your mouse to a certain position and trigger a click when a keyboard button was pressed. That tool might still work on windows, but I was planning to build something similar for Mac (or with node.js even system wide) and not warcraft specific.

I googled a lot and found several tools to move the mouse and send keys as [nodemacmouse](https://github.com/Loknar/node-macmouse) or [robojs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs), but I could not find anything to detect system wide keyboard input (which is crucial since the movements should only happen on key-press). This seems to be do-able [in cocoa](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) but a node solution would be flawless. Is it possible? How? Thanks.

Comment: Electron can do this: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md

You could either look into their implementation, or simply build a headless electron app.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to find a package that would pick up keyboard events, but this package gets the job done for me on Ubuntu and OpenWRT:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-event

From the documentation:

```
var InputEvent = require('input-event');

var input = new InputEvent('/dev/input/event0');

var keyboard = new InputEvent.Keyboard(input);

keyboard.on('keyup'   , console.log);
keyboard.on('keydown' , console.log);
keyboard.on('keypress', console.log);
```